# Failed to load resource resulting on a not working javascript I need to know where im wrong

Tags: javascript, html

Failed to load resource resulting on a not working javascript I need to know where im wrong

**Heres my a1.html file**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsA1.js"></script> //error here
    <script>
        var v = prompt("Enter the velocity(meters)");
        var t = prompt("Enter the time(seconds)");
        calcDistance(v,t);    //error ^^ up there resulting calcDistance to be undefined

        var m = prompt("Enter the mass");
        var a = prompt("Enter the acceleration");
        calcForce(m,a);

        var c = prompt("Enter temperature(celcius)");
        var far = calcFarenheit(c);
        var farenheitAlert = c + " celcius is " +far +" farenheit";
        alert(farenheitAlert);
   </script>
</body>
```

**Here is the external jsA1.js file:**

```
function calcDistance(velocity, time)

{
  return alert("With the velocity of " + velocity + " and time of " + time + " the distance is " +(velocity*time));       
  }

  function calcForce(mass,acceleration)

  {
      return alert("With the mass of "+mass+" and the acceleration of "+acceleration+" the force is "+ mass/acceleration);

  }

  function calcFarenheit(celcius)
  {

return (celcius -32) *5 / 9;

  }
```

Comment: The solution in the question's title. Check the path.

Comment: make sure that jsA1.js exists in the same folder

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow as well as being a beginner in web dev. I ask really dumb questions. @PSK I made sure it was on the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Your external js file need to be refreshed. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> I think this command may help u.